# Typing compose when some of arguments are generic or anonymous

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, function-composition

I would like to have a `compose` function that implements function composition. I want the definition of `compose` to be type-safe, allow for as many arguments as desired, and to handle arguments that are themselves generic or anonymous to be typed correctly. This last requirement has been a stumbling block for me.

My current definition, using [Recursive Conditional Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-rc/#recursive-conditional-types) as found in the Typescript 4.1 Release Candidate:

```
type Compose<Fns extends any[]> =
    Fns extends [(...args: infer Args) => infer Return] ? (...args: Args) => Return :
    Fns extends [(...args: infer Args0) => infer Ret0, (arg: infer Arg1) => Ret1, ...infer Rest] ? (
        [Ret0, Arg1] extends [Arg1, Ret0] ? Compose<[(...args: Args0) => Ret1, ...Rest]> :
        never
    ) :
    never;

declare function compose<Fns extends ((...args: any[]) => any)[]>(
    ...fns: Fns
): Compose<Fns>;
```

This works perfectly when all of the functions have fixed, defined types:

```
declare function foo(x1: string, x2: number): number;
declare function bar(y: number): boolean;
declare function baz(z: boolean): string;

const foobarbaz = compose(foo, bar, baz); // (x1: string, x2: number) => string
```

The problem comes in when one of the functions passed to `compose` is generic:

```
declare function foo(x: string): number;
declare function bar<T>(foo: T): string;

const foobar = compose(foo, bar); // typed as `never`
```

Here, `foobar` is `never` because the `[Arg1, Ret0] extends [Ret0, Arg1]` check in `Compose` fails. That check fails because `bar`’s `T` parameter, and therefore `Arg1`, is inferred as `unknown`, and `[unknown, number]` indeed does not extend `[number, unknown]`. But of course, `T` (and `Arg1`) *could be* `number`, in which case `[number, number] extends [number, number]` would pass. Typescript will automatically infer generic parameters like this in many cases, but not here.

The same problem can be seen with anonymous functions:

```
declare function foo(x: string): number;

const foobar = compose(foo, x => x.toLocaleString()); // typed as `(x: string) => any`
```

Here, `x` is an implicit `any`, rather than being implicitly `number` as indicated by the return value of `foo`.

Ultimately, these problems are not terribly surprising: the restriction on one function’s return value and the next function’s argument comes from `Compose`, which isn’t used until the return value on `compose`. By the time TS gets around to dealing with that, the argument and the generic parameter have already been evaluated.

I have tried to redefine things so that there is an actual sense within the argument of `compose` that functions must be related, rather than just allowing `((...args: any[]) => any)[]`, but so far that hasn’t gotten anywhere. Typescript continues to just infer `any` or `unknown` and the overall typing just breaks.

For reference, here was that attempt:

```
type Composable<Types extends any[]> = Tail<Types> extends infer Tail ? Tail extends any[] ? {
    [I in keyof Tail]: I extends keyof Types ? (arg: Types[I]) => Tail[I] : never;
} : never : never;

declare function compose<Fns extends Composable<T>, T extends any[]>(...fns: Fns): Compose<Fns>;
```

<sup>(`Tail` is a type that evaluates to the passed array type sans its first member—here, `Tail[I]` corresponds to the next item in the series after `Types[I]`)</sup>

But this just uses `any[]` for `T`, and then `Composable<T>` winds up being the same `((arg: any) => any)[]` I had before. So it’s no help.

Without trying to use a conditional type, we can write non-variadic versions of `compose` that get around this (because each argument is defined in terms of the previous), but then they can only handle some hard-coded number of functions. This is, mostly likely, the solution I’ll go with, but my goal with this question is to avoid that.

Comment: This is a tough ask because you are trying to enforce that each element of the arguments array of `compose` depends on the previous element.  As far as I know, that cannot be done.  You would need a mapped type where each `I` can get the return type from `I - 1`, but that sort of operation doesn't exist.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I can totally do that—writing a `Subtract<X, Y>` type isn’t too hard (for non-negative integers, anyway) and my `Tail` implementation basically amounts to the same thing—but unfortunately it’s too complex/too many layers of indirection for TS to “understand” the relationship you’re describing. Which is totally understandable but man I really want a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As of TypeScript 4.7 you can help the compiler by using [instantiation expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#instantiation-expressions).

The ideal situation would be the compiler tracking the generic expression when deriving Parameters / ReturnType, but this is still not achievable AFAICT.

```
declare function foo(x: string): number;
declare function bar<T>(foo: T): string;

const foobar = compose(foo, bar<string>);
```

Comment: I can’t believe that feature took this long. I assumed it didn’t exist because some technical issue made it impossible. I remember a conversation with a co-worker about it—over 5 years ago. Well, glad it’s in now.